# Why the numbersl for v-axis of google chart shows in points?

Tags: google-visualization

this is my chart from google chart.

[image: chart]

This is the options code for the chart:

```
 var optionsCategoryNameChart = {
                             //title: 'Job/Internship Distribution by Category',
                             titleTextStyle: {
                                  color: 'Black',
                                  fontSize: 18
                                },
                                pieSliceText: 'none',
                             fontSize: '11',
                             hAxis: {
                                  title: 'Category Name',
                                },
                             vAxis: {
                                  title: 'Total',
                                  minValue: 0,
                                  ticks: [0,1,2,3]          
                                },
                             legend: {textStyle: {color: '#464847', fontSize: 11}},
                             tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                             backgroundColor: '#F8F9FA',
                             colors: [ '#3B84BB', '#FFAF45', '#FFE345', '#0CAA63', '#1D40A6', '#F7AE12', '#F75012','#6944C3'],
                             chartArea: {
                                    backgroundColor: {
                                        stroke: '#fff',
                                        strokeWidth: 1
                                    }
                                },
                             height: 300,
                             chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"20%",width:"80%",height:"50%" }
                              };
```

I do not set the v-axis as float numbers or anything else but why it comes out as float numbers?
How I want to change it to numbers 0,1,2,3,4? I tried with

```
minValue: 0,
```

but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vAxis.ticks` will override all other settings,
given the y-axis values are numbers

to create `ticks` dynamically from the data,
you data table method --> `getColumnRange`

you can also use `format` to ensure whole numbers

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'CATEGORY');
    data.addColumn('number', 'JOB');
    data.addColumn('number', 'INTERNSHIP');
    data.addRows([
      ['Design', 1, 2],
      ['Construction', 3, 4]
    ]);

    // find range of each y-axis column
    var range = {
      max: 0,
      min: 0
    };
    if (data.getNumberOfRows() > 0) {
      for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        var colRange = data.getColumnRange(i);
        range.max = Math.max(range.max, colRange.max);
        range.min = Math.min(range.min, colRange.min);
      }
    }

    // build ticks from range
    var ticks = [];
    for (var i = range.min; i <= range.max; i++) {
      ticks.push(i);
    }

    var options = {
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'Black',
        fontSize: 18
      },
      fontSize: '11',
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Category Name',
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Total',
        ticks: ticks,
        format: '#,##0'
      },
      legend: {textStyle: {color: '#464847', fontSize: 11}},
      tooltip: {isHtml: true},
      backgroundColor: '#F8F9FA',
      colors: [ '#3B84BB', '#FFAF45', '#FFE345', '#0CAA63', '#1D40A6', '#F7AE12', '#F75012','#6944C3'],
      chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: {
          stroke: '#fff',
          strokeWidth: 1
        }
      },
      height: 300,
      chartArea: {
        bottom: 48,
        left: 36,
        right: 12,
        top: 12,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I am sorry for going away for few days. I already tried yours, I take out the 'tick' options and put in the format. It appears as whole numbers but it rounded the points to whole numbers make the numbers in vertical axis redundant.

Comment: my database only got 2 or 3 counted numbers. is that why the chart shows the vertical values in points?

Comment: if the values are small, the chart will use decimals in order to add a few ticks to the y-axis -- must use `ticks` to override, use in combination with `format` to not show decimals or duplicate whole numbers -- use `getColumnRange` to build `ticks` dynamically from the data -- see changed answer above...

Comment: it works @WhiteHat. Thank you so  much for your help.